# A self-taught road from Algebra to Higher Maths

Tags: self-learning, advice

I was wondering if there is a clear roadmap from algebra all the way to Topology, Real Analysis and Complex Analysis? Apologies if what I’m asking is naive but I’ve just taken a re-kindled interest to math recently.

A little bit about me:

I an a computer science graduate who works 8 hours a day, and have about 3 hours of spare time to study math everyday. The “spark” to take math again was because I wanted to learn the underlying foundation of computer science, which is discrete math. Eventually I wanted to learn more math and decided to aim for an area which requires numerous prerequisites so in that way I have a roadmap to higher areas of math and learn their applications (if any). I self-study, so books are my primary source of information. I know it’s a long road, all the way maybe to 20 or more years, but I am dedicated to it, just for the sake that I find math fun.

Currently I would probably need to refresh myself with algebra, trigonometry, and then start seriously with maybe Set Theory, then learning how to prove theorems. Is this the right sequence to study it?

Again, sorry if I’m asking a very naive question, and thanks for helping.

Comment: before analysis, you should study calculus, if you haven't already

Comment: The excellent introductory course to mathematical thinking on coursera : https://www.coursera.org/learn/mathematical-thinking. A great course about maths and proofs, a great and inspiring way to begin.

Comment: Please take a look at Gelfand and Shen, "Algebra".  Gelfand also has a book on trigonometry.  Kodaira also has some great books to get started (e.g. Mathematics I:  Japanese Grade 10).

Comment: The roadmap from algebra also could go all the way up from algebra to modern number theory, or to cryptography and coding theory. Why do you restrict yourself to Topology, Real Analysis and Complex Analysis?

Comment: If it's just general math you want, my suggestion is 1) algebra, 2) trig, 3) 1D calculus, 4) 2D and 3D calculus, 5) ordinary differential equations, 6) partial diff. eqns., 7) linear algebra, 8) calculus of complex variables.  I put linear algebra at 7 pretty arbitrarily.  It can be done any time after algebra, but its uses become apparent if you know some of the other stuff.  If you get to this point, you're getting into the major leagues.  At this point I would do differential geometry, then finally start the topics you mentioned, topology etc.